# Why is this DataSet empty?

Tags: c#, dataset

I have created a new WinForms project as a demo, added a new Service-database to the project, added a table `User` to the database and used the Server Explorer to add some data to the database.

However, when I add a `DataSet` to my main form and attempt to query the dataset, I always receive an empty response. Why is that? What am I doing wrong?

---

Here is a step-by-step list of things I did:

1. Create a new WinForms app called "DemoApp"
2. Right click the project, select "Add..." then add a new Service-Based Database "DemoDB"
3. DemoDB now shows up in the data connections
4. Add a new table with the following characteristics:

   ```
   CREATE TABLE [dbo].[User]
   (
       [Id] INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, 
       [Username] VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL unique
   )
   ```
5. Add demo data to that table through the Data Connections tab.
6. Add a new button to the main form
7. Add a new Data Source to the project by selecting "Database" > "Dataset", then selecting "DemoDB.mdf". The connection will be saved as "DemoDBConnectionString".
8. Select all tables for the DataSet "DemoDBDataSet". The DemoDBDataSet now shows up in the Data Sources tab.
9. Add a new data set into the Main Form, selecting DemoApp.DemoDBDataSet
10. Add an event handler to the button with the following code:

    ```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (var item in this.demoDBDataSet1.User)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(item.ToString());
        }
    }
    ```

I would expect that it would iterate through the users and print them, but when looking at it from the debugger, `this.demoDBDataSet1.User` is empty. Why?

Comment: I'm not familiar with service based databases connections, but it's not clear (to me) why you name your table `Table`, with attributes `Id` and `Username`, and then look for a `User` in the dataset.

Comment: @topsail That was a copying mistake on my end. I fixed that, but forgot to update the question.

Answer (score 2):

So after more digging and looking into [this documentation page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/data-tools/fill-datasets-by-using-tableadapters?view=vs-2022&tabs=csharp) it turns out that the dataset needs to be filled manually before it can be used.

This code in the form construcor achieves this:

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    UserTableAdapter adapter = new UserTableAdapter();
    adapter.Fill(this.demoDBDataSet1.User);
}
```